# Shiny wellpanel height not the same as text in it

Tags: r, shiny, formatting

Issue:
Trying to put textinput options in a wellpanel for aesthetic purposes, but the height of well panel is not the same as the information in it. See image below. [image]

When I don't use column(), I don't have a problem, but I prefer to condense the space taken up by the textinput().

Relevant Code:

```
tags$style(tableHTML::make_css(list('.well', 'border-width', '5px')))

        column(8,
               wellPanel(
                         column(4, textInput("text1", h4("Name"), width = "60%",
                                          value = "Jane Doe"),
                                   textInput("text3", h4("Wind"), width = "60%",
                                          value = "x")),
                         column(4, textInput("text2", h4("Temperature"), width = "60%",
                                          value = "x"),
                                   textInput("text4", h4("Water"), width = "60%",
                                          value = "x")))

        )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `column`s must always be enclosed in a `fluidRow`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           wellPanel(
             fluidRow(
               column(4, textInput("text1", h4("Name"), width = "60%",
                                   value = "Jane Doe"),
                      textInput("text3", h4("Wind"), width = "60%",
                                value = "x")),
               column(4, textInput("text2", h4("Temperature"), width = "60%",
                                   value = "x"),
                      textInput("text4", h4("Water"), width = "60%",
                                value = "x"))
             )
           )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input,output){})
```